# Trouble inserting data into sqlite database with JDBC

Tags: sqlite, jdbc, kotlin

This is what my code currently looks like:

```
import java.sql.*
import java.sql.SQLException

class SqliteDB {

val conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:cs2820-database.db")

fun createUser123(userID: String, password: String, adminStatus: String) {

    val statement = conn.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO Users(id,pass,admin) VALUES(?,?,?)")
    statement.setString(1, userID)
    statement.setString(2,password)
    statement.setString(3,adminStatus)
    println("123")
    statement.executeUpdate()
    conn.commit()
    println("User Created")

}

// create a user
fun createUser(userID: String, password: String, adminStatus: String) {
    println("inside createUser")
    val sql = "INSERT INTO Users(id,pass,admin) VALUES(?,?,?)"
    Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC")

    try {
        conn.use { conn ->
            conn.prepareStatement(sql).use { pstmt ->
                pstmt.setString(1, userID)
                pstmt.setString(2, password)
                pstmt.setString(3, adminStatus)
                pstmt.executeUpdate()
                //conn.commit()
                pstmt.close()
            }
        }
    } catch (e: SQLException) {
        println(e.message)
    }

}
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val db = SqliteDB()

    db.createUser("Jim", "password", "false")
}
```

I have tested two different `createUser` methods and most everything I have tried will return the error [SQLITE_BUSY]  The database file is locked (database is locked). I have several other methods within the same SqliteDB class that query data ("SELECT") that all work correctly, but every time I try to perform any kind of update of information I am given the same error. I am at a loss for what to do at this point having searched many different forums and posts about syntax and such.

The full stacktrace is as follows:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.sqlite.SQLiteException: [SQLITE_BUSY]  The database file is locked (database is locked)
    at org.sqlite.core.DB.newSQLException(DB.java:909)
    at org.sqlite.core.DB.newSQLException(DB.java:921)
    at org.sqlite.core.DB.execute(DB.java:822)
    at org.sqlite.core.DB.executeUpdate(DB.java:863)
    at org.sqlite.jdbc3.JDBC3PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(JDBC3PreparedStatement.java:99)
    at SqliteDB.createUser(SqliteDB.kt:50)
    at SqliteDBKt.main(SqliteDB.kt:122)
```

I don't believe the issue is with an open connection as the error seems to occur as soon as I try to execute the update to the User table. The insert seems to hit some sort of loop of some kind at the execution stage.

**EDIT**: Something else I noticed, is that when attempting to create a new user with a primary key (userID) that already exists, I am given a uniqueness error, suggesting the update is going thru and realizing the userID is already in the table; however, there is still the issue with the INSERT creating a **new** row in the table. I'm just not sure how to go about debugging that specific issue.

Comment: I am not familiar with Kotlin langage but I think it happens because of not closing the connections after every db action.

Comment: Please post the full exception stacktrace

Comment: Updated with exception stacktrace

Answer (score 0):

So this has been quite an issue for me for the past week or so and it looks like I have been able to figure out the issue.

I am aware that you have to make sure to close any connections to the database before opening a new one to avoid locks and any other similar issues. What I did not realize is that I have been using a program in IntelliJ called "DB Browser". This plugin creates a UI that much more easily allows you to access and change any aspect of the database you want without using actual SQL commands. What I didn't realize is this plugin takes up the only writeable connection the SQLite and JDBC allow to the database.

So, after deleting the connection to the database through the DB Browser plugin, all of my functions are working properly.